Prove the index of a proper subgroup of a simple group of order 17971200 is at least 14.
I didn't find a solution for this problem or other usual approaches that could directly work. So, here is my attempt. I am self-studying and reviewing group theory recently, and would like to know if my proof is correct. Thank you!
Let $G$ be a simple group of order 17971200, and $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G$.
Prove that $[G:H]\geq 14$.
Proof.
Claim 1. $[G:H]\geq 13, \forall H<G.$
Assume to the contrary, $[G:H]<13$.
Then, there exists $n=[G:H]$, $2\leq n \leq 12.$
By Sylow theorem I, there exists a Sylow $P$-group of $G$, $P<G$ such that $\vert P \vert = 13^r, r\in\mathbb{N}$.
By Cayley theorem, $G\hookrightarrow A_n <S_n$.
By Lagrange theorem, $13$ divides $\vert P\vert$, and $\vert P\vert$ divides $\vert A_n\vert = \frac{n!}{2}.$
However, $2\cdot 13$ does not divide $n!$ for $2\leq n\leq 12.$
Claim 2. $[G:H]\geq 14, \forall H<G.$
Based on the proof of Claim 1, since $[G:H]$ is a positive integer, it suffices to show $[G:H]\neq 13$.
Assume there exists $H<G$ such that $[G:H]=13$.
Then $\vert G \vert = 13 \vert H \vert$ by Lagrange theorem.
By Cayley theorem, $G\hookrightarrow S_n$.
By Lagrange's theorem again, $\vert G\vert \big\vert \vert S_{13}\vert = 13!.$
Then, $13 \cdot \vert H\vert \big\vert 13!.$ Thus, $\cdot \vert H\vert \big\vert 12!.$
On the other hand, $\vert H \vert = \frac{\vert G \vert}{13} = 2^{11}\cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^2.$ (Notice that $\vert G \vert = 17971200=2^{11}\cdot 3^3\cdot 5^2 \cdot 13.$)
However, $2^{11}\nmid 12!$. Therefore, the assumption is false.
Finally, by Claim 2, the order of every proper subgroup of the group $G$ is at least 14.

Some questions for you:

Why is Sylow's theorem necessary in your claim 1? (i.e. why can't you just proceed as in Claim 2?)
In Claim 1, why does $G$ have image in $A_n$?
In both Claim 1 and 2, why does $G$ inject into $S_n$? (In particular, how is simplicity of the group related to this?)


From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: "A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."

The appearance of 14 makes me think of Kuratowski's closure-complement theorem. I doubt there is any relationship, though it would be amusing if there were.

@dummy 1. the necessity of claim 1 is to exclude all the possibilities from 3 to 12 (2 could be excluded by since the group is simple), and obtained a lower bound, i.e. $[G:H]>13$. Then, claim 2 improves the lower bound obtained from claim 1 from 13 to 14. Sylow I provides a subgroup with an order to be some powers of 13. For 2, again, $G$ is a simple group, and $[G:H]=n$, so $G$ can be embedded into $A_n$. If not, then the embedding has a non-trivial normal subgroup in $G$, by correspondence theorem, a contradiction. 3. Injecting into $S_n$ is a way to generate contradiction.

@Shaun Because I didn't find a solution for this problem or other usual approaches that could directly work, and since this problem is new to me, I would like to know if it's a correct proof. I would also like to learn from comments to improve my proof writing skills. Additionally, whenever it's possible, I would like to know (or to exchange) alternative way to solve this problem.

@martycohen Thank you for bringing this Kuratowski's closure-complement theorem up!


In claim 1, the gist of your argument is that |P| does not divide |An| (you argued by 13 divides the former but not the latter). You could have done the exact same thing with G in place of P, hence removing the use of sylows theorem. This is how you argued in claim 2 as well.  2. Your argument correctly shows that G injects into Sn, and should have been hifhlighted in your proof (this is how you used simplicity of the group). However, you did not explain why in claim 1, the image lies in An instead of Sn. That part is not clear at all.


Let $G$ be a nontrivial finite group and $X_G$ the set of all the proper subgroups of $G$, $X_G:=\{H\le G\mid H\ne G\}$. Lagrange's theorem already puts a limitation on the order of the elements of $X_G$, which must be a proper divisor of $|G|$. If $G$ is simple, then an additional limitation on the order of the elements of $X_G$ sets in, namely:
$$G\space\text{simple}\Longrightarrow|G|\mid[G:H]!, \space\forall H\in X_G \tag 1$$
In fact, for $H\in X_G$, the group $G$ acts by left multiplication on the left quotient set $G/H$, and this action has trivial kernel, being $G$ simple. So, $G$ embeds into $S_{[G:H]}$, whence $(1)$.
For $[G:H]<13$, $(1)$ is false because $13\nmid [G:H]!$ (recall that $13$ is a factor of $|G|$). The case $[G:H]=13$ is ruled out by direct calculation,  which yields $\frac{[G:H]!}{|G|}=\frac{3^2.7.11}{2}$, not an integer.
